# How to Find memory Leak issue in Application

Tags: hikaricp

Does anyone know what improvements have been applied in version 2.8.0 over version 2.7.9 of hikariCP to manage database connection pools? I have a memory leak problem in my application and I am using  Spring Data with the standard methods of JpaRepository, that is, I am not controlling the opening and closing of the connection manually.

It may also be a website with the improvements applied to each version.

Comment: Why not ask [the developers through their github project](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)? As an aside: I am unable to find a 2.8.x version. Do you mean 3.0.0?

Comment: HikariCP has no leaks. Look elsewhere. Suggestion: take a heap dump and use heap analyzer.

Comment: The latest HikariCP is 3.4.2. If you suspect you have a problem with HikariCP, then first upgrade to the latest version. If you want to know what changed between versions, look at https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/CHANGES. FYI, there never was a 2.8.0 looking at https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP and https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/releases

Comment: I thought I would have version 2.8.0, I will consult version 3.0.0 as you mentioned. I would not just like to upgrade to the latest version without knowing what improvements have been made from one version to another. Thanks for the help.